# Django counting one to many relationship

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

So i have two tables, ***Post*** and ***Category***

Code:

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
     category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.category
```

---

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
     content = models.TextField()
     created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ['-created_date']

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title + ' - ' + str(self.created_date.date())
```

And I want to implement category list in template. For example I have few categories

Sports(2) `2-number of how many posts are within sports category`

template code:

```
<h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul class="nav navbar-stacked">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li><a href="#">{{ category }}<span class="pull-right">(
                {{ **post.category.count** }}
            )</span></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In template, you can do

```
{{ category.post_set.count }}
```

to get count of `Post` objects with `category` mapped to given category object.

You can read more about reverse lookups [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: 4 more minutes, it seems that I can't accept if 15min is not passed :)